# Mel check if unresolved name exists

Tags: maya, mel

How can I check if a reference with a particular unresolved name is loaded using an if statement. Thanks

Pseudo code example

If (referenceLoaded "C:/bridge.ma"){ do stuff}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the erroring out issue by using catch

`if (catch(!`referenceQuery -isLoaded "C:/bridge.ma"`)) {
  continue; 
}
else if (`referenceQuery -isLoaded "C:/bridge.ma"`) {
  print("reference is loaded");
}`

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like

`referenceQuery -isLoaded "C:/bridge.ma";`

Which will return a 1 or 0 if the file is loaded or not.

Heres a rough example of the above in an if statement:

```
if (!`referenceQuery -isLoaded "C:/bridge.ma"`)
    print("reference not loaded");

else if (`referenceQuery -isLoaded "C:/bridge.ma"`)
    print("reference is loaded");
```

Comment: Thanks. It wored beautifully

Comment: Sorry but I realize that it doesn't work as well as i want it to. It only works if the file as been referenced that is, it appears in the reference editor. However, I would like to beable to detect if the file is actually referenced. Right now the current code throws an error "please specify a reference node, referenced file, or node from a referenced file." I think it's because the file was never referenced before. But if the file was referenced but just not loaded, the code would work.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I realize that it doesn't work as well as i want it to. It only works if the file as been referenced that is, it appears in the reference editor. However, I would like to beable to detect if the file is actually referenced. Right now the current code throws an error "please specify a reference node, referenced file, or node from a referenced file." I think it's because the file was never referenced before. But if the file was referenced but just not loaded, the code would work.